# Plot for 100 random surveys

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to reproduce the following graph in R:

[image]

This is meant to represent 100 random polls confidence intervals, with a mean of 42.9. I made some progress with qplot, however there are some things that I still couldn't get.

```
library(ggplot2)

polls <- replicate(100, rnorm(100, mean = 30, sd=3))

# Calculate 90% confidence intervals for each row.

tint <- matrix(NA, nrow = dim(polls)[2], ncol = 2)
for (i in 1:dim(polls)[2]) {
  temp <- t.test(polls[, i], conf.level = 0.9)
  tint[i, ] <- temp$conf.int
}
colnames(tint) <- c("lcl", "ucl")

# The width of each confidence interval:

width <- apply(tint, 1, diff)
tint <- cbind(tint, width)
tint <- data.frame(tint)
```

And with the command:

```
qplot(tint$width, y=30, geom="pointrange",ymin = tint$lcl, ymax = tint$ucl) + coord_flip() + 
  theme_bw()
```

I get:

[image]

Questions:

- How do I change y to represent each poll?
- How to draw the line at the intended mean (30, in this case)?

Comment: Y values are not evenly distributed (this is the nature of the data you present), is this really how your data is?

Comment: Should the y-axis be categorical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a very elegant solution but it works:

```
ggplot(data = tint, aes(x = ucl - width/2, y = seq(1:100))) +
 geom_point() + 
 geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = lcl, xmax = ucl)) + 
 geom_vline(xintercept = 30, color = "red")
```

[image]